# state in react with redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have 3 questions about `state` in react with redux

the first one is that, as I know, `state` is an object. But from where can I know the fields in the `state` object?

the second one is that, from the [todomvc official example](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/todomvc/src/components/TodoItem.js), there is one state:

```
state = {
    editing: false
  }

  handleDoubleClick = () => {
    this.setState({ editing: true })
  }
```

in my understanding, `setState` would update the global state. so does that mean this state is global not local? and the state only has one field `editing`?

```
 state = {
        editing: false
      }
```

my last question is that, currently I am using angular to develop my website, which has 3 pages, e.g. `www.example.com/invoice`, `www.example.com/customers`, and `www.example.com/suppliers`. for each page, I would use angular to fetch data from backend. so if I want to rewrite it in react with redux, the state should be something like below?

```
{
    type: xxx,
    invoiceData: xxx,
    customerData: xxx,
    supplierData: xxx,
    //some other cool stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Usually, if you want to change or access the state, you have previously defined its fields. That's what you do with `state = {editing: false}`.
2. I think that you are mixing react's state with Redux. The state of Redux is global to the app, but in this example you are not using Redux. **This state is React's component state, so it's only accessible locally** in the component. `setState` is a React function that asynchronously mutates the state of the component. After setState is called, the component is re-rendered.
3. I think that this question is unclear because, as I said, you might be confused with React and Redux. Try to understand [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/) by itself first and then take a look at [Redux](http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/).